# Want to fetch the data entered in jsp, collect it and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have entered a values in 1st jsp in text box as "a" and fetched the value "a". next i have to redirect from first jsp to second jsp using next button. In 2nd jsp i enter one value "b" and click ok button in 2nd jsp i want to collect value "b" and store somewhere so that when i come back to check entered "b" value must be there . now i want to go back to first jsp and display the contents i entered in 1st jsp which is value "a".

Please suggest soluition, Javascript or jquery solution is helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

store values in cookies. https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ might be useful